# Swift 3 - Sending message with image - Undetermined Literal

Tags: swift, image, message, mfmessagecomposeviewcontroller

Currently trying to open `MFMessageComposeViewController` with an image attached but the `typeIdentifier` that I have found in older code seems to not be the right fit and I'm not able to find any documentation regarding attaching an image to a message other than copying the image to the PasteBoard/clipboard then having the user manually paste it in the message.

```
func sendMessageWith(imageData: Data) -> MFMessageComposeViewController? {
  if MFMessageComposeViewController.canSendText() == true {
      let composeVC = MFMessageComposeViewController()
      composeVC.messageComposeDelegate = self
      composeVC.addAttachmentData(imageData, typeIdentifier: kUTTypeJPEG, filename: "image.jpg")

      print("OK")
      return composeVC
    }

  print("Try Again")
  return nil
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import `MobileCoreServices` framework:

```
import MobileCoreServices
```

which contains the `UTCoreTypes` header which contains `kUTTypeJPEG`.

and you have to cast the constant to `String` because it's a `CFString`:

```
composeVC.addAttachmentData(
    imageData,
    typeIdentifier: kUTTypeJPEG as String,
    filename: "image.jpg"
)
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you :D